# Microsoft Graph ASPNET Webhooks code sample works on ngrok but not on azure

Tags: api, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying the code sample from: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-Webhooks and it is working fine on ngrok but I get this issue on azure when creating subscription.
[image]

Any suggestions to look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be related to the app permissions.  Check the application permissions for the proper level of access to the resource.  For example, set the "Read user mail" permission if you want to subscribe to email notifications.  Also ensure that the token being used for creating the subscription has access to the resource.

This is related to the permissions in the token and not a hosting difference between Azure or ngrok.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I found out it was more on clientId and client secret. I used the app registration tool generated Ids and somewhere decided to add it manually on AAD but was still referencing those generated by app registration tool.